# while page yet, i have set everything

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to make via `hi` in view but its give me white page display. I have created controller and view ... path is also set in `web.php`

ROUTE:

```
Route::post('/member/add-single-trade/import_single_trades_parse', 'trades\ImportSingleTradesController@tradesImport');
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    public function tradesImport()
{
    return view('member.add-single-trade.import-excel.import_fields', compact( ''));
}
```

BLADE: `import_fields.blade.php`

```
hi
```

Comment: Its giving only `white blank page`.

Comment: try to change method post to get Route::get()

Comment: i already done this with `get method` in route

Comment: I don't think using post method you can open your route in web

Comment: Why r using `compact()` fn? You don't seem to pass any values.

Comment: i ll pass later and i have checked without `compact`. @thebrownkid

Comment: I have tired with `get` @DharmeshRakholia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:** underscore does not work in route: `/member/add-single-trade/import_single_trades_parse`

It's working with : `/member/add-single-trade/import-single-trades-parse`

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just return 'hi' in tradesImport() to see whether the route works fine